# Detect action mailer delivery failures in after_action callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am using an `after_action` callback in my mailers to record that email was sent.  The emails are sent through Delayed Job.  This works, except when we are unable to reach the remote server - in which case, the email is not sent, but we record that it was.  Delayed Job retries the email later, and it is successfully delivered, but we've then recorded that two emails were sent.

It looks something like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  after_action :record_email

  def record_email
   Rails.logger.info("XYZZY: Recording Email")
   @user.emails.create!
  end

  def spam!(user) 
   @user = user
   Rails.logger.info("XYZZY: Sending spam!")
   m = mail(to: user.email, subject: 'SPAM!')
   Rails.logger.info("XYZZY: mail method finished")
   m
  end
end
```

I call this code like this (using [delayed job performable mailer):](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb)

```
UserMailer.delay.spam!( User.find(1))
```

When I step through this in a debugger, it seems that my after_action method is called before the mail is delivered.

```
[Job:104580969] XYZZY: Sending spam!
[Job:104580969] XYZZY: mail method finished
[Job:104580969] XYZZY: Recording Email
Job UserMailer.app_registration_welcome (id=104580969) FAILED (3 prior attempts) with Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 1025
```

How can I catch network errors in my mailer methods and record that the email attempt failed, or do nothing at all?  I'm using Rails 4.2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with, I would love to have a better way.

I used the Mail delivery callback:

**delivery_callback.rb**

```
class DeliveryCallback
  def delivered_email(mail)
    data = mail.instance_variable_get(:@_callback_data)
    unless data.nil?
      data[:user].email.create!
    end
  end
end
```

**config/initializes/mail.rb**

```
Mail.register_observer( DeliveryCallback.new )
```

And I replaced my record_email method:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  after_action :record_email

  def record_email
    @_message.instance_variable_set(:@_callback_data, {:user => user}) 
  end
end
```

This seems to work, if the remote server is not available, the delivered_email callback is not invoked.

***Is there a better way!?!?***

Comment: I think this is the best way, aligns with the documentation:  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-and-observing-emails

Answer (score 1):

In [rails 7.1+](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html) there are `before_deliver`, `around_deliver`, `after_deliver` callbacks

```rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  after_deliver :make_something_after_deliver

  def send_mail
    mail to: "email@example.com", subject: "Email"
  end

  private

  def make_something_after_deliver
    # make something after deliver
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The debug messages you showed make perfect sense - the mailer action finishes immediately because the mailing action itself is **asynchronous**, handled by Delayed job in a completely different process. So there is no way the mailer class itself can know how the mailing action finished.

What I think you need instead is implementing **[Delayed job hooks](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks)**. You'd have to rewrite your mailers and the calls to send emails a bit though.

I have not tested it fully but something along the following lines should work:

```
class MailerJob

  def initialize(mailer_class, mailer_action, recipient, *params)
    @mailer_class = mailer_class
    @mailer_action = mailer_action
    @recipient = recipient
    @params = params
  end

  def perform
    @mailer_class.send(@mailer_action, @recipient, *@params)
  end

  def success(job)
    Rails.logger.debug "recording email!"
    @recipient.emails.create!
  end

  def failure(job)
    Rails.logger.debug "sending email to #{@recipient.email} failed!"
  end

end
```

`MailerJob` is a [custom job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs) to be run by Delayed job. I tried to make it as general as possible, so it accepts the mailer class, the mailer action, the recipient (typically the user) and other optional params. Also it requires the `recipient` to have the `emails` association.

The job has two hooks defined: `success` when the mailing action succeeds which creates the `email` record in the database and another one for logging failure. The actual sending is done in the `perform` method. Note that inside it the `delayed` method is not used as the whole job is already enqueued in a background Delayed job queue when being called.

To send a mail using this custom job you have to **enqueue it to Delayed job**, e.g.:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue MailerJob.new(UserMailer, :spam!, User.find(1))
```

Comment: My co-worker suggested this.  I think its a pretty good idea, but I would extend the functionality of Delayed::PerformableMailer (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/v4.1.1/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb).  I think you are wrong about the mailing action being asynchronous.  You are right that from where I call UserMailer.delay.spam! the mail method happens later, but the actual job of sending the email is synchronous within delayed job.

Comment: I meant "asynchronous" in the sense that the mailer action does not wait for the result of the actual mailing (done by delayed job). And I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what problem do you have with the hooks approach? From the [source](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/2014009496dd0b2af217ab322f74f91fe4e26097/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb#L2) it seems that internally the PerformableMailer is nothing but a class that enqueues mailing jobs pretty much in the same way as my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks after successful delivery are called observers in action mailer and available since rails 3.x.

From
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#observing-emails :

> An observer class must implement the :delivered_email(message) method, which will be called after the email is sent.

```
class EmailDeliveryObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    EmailDelivery.log(message)
  end
end
```

> Similar to interceptors, you must register observers using the observers config option. You can do this in an initializer file like config/initializers/mail_observers.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.observers = %w[EmailDeliveryObserver]
end
```

There is also a [`register_observer`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-c-register_observer) class method to add an observer only to a specific mailer.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  # after_action :record_email

  def record_email
   Rails.logger.info("XYZZY: Recording Email")
   @user.emails.create!
  end

  def spam!(user)
    begin 
      @user = user
      Rails.logger.info("XYZZY: Sending spam!")
      m = mail(to: user.email, subject: 'SPAM!')
      Rails.logger.info("XYZZY: mail method finished")
      m
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      record_email  
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It has a little bit with how delayed job processes the email.  It calls your mailer method then invoked delivery (or deliver_now) on it.  So the actually delivery is performed outside of the spam! method

Comment: I also want something that works without having to remember to implement it on every mailer method or chagne all my existing mailer methods (there are about 30)